# (Java) Program gives me an illegal type of expression and ";" expected even when I actually typed in a semi colon

Tags: java, string

I am getting an error that starts with illegal type of expression and ";" expected and not a statement.

My code goes like this:

> String final = new String();
>   // it gets an error saying that I didn't put a semi colon and is an illegal type of expression.

```
        String final = new String();
        for (int x = 0; x < encrypted.length() - 1; x += 3)
        {
            int pair1X = SearchX(char(encrypted.substring(x, 1));
            int pair1Y = SearchY(char(encrypted.substring(x, 1));
            int pair2X = SearchX(char(encrypted.substring(x + 1, 1)), box);
            int pair2Y = SearchY(char(encrypted.substring(x + 1, 1)), box);
            if (pair1X == pair2X)
            {
                pair1Y++;
                if (pair1Y > 4)
                {
                    pair1Y = 0;
                }
                pair2Y++;
                if (pair2Y > 4)
                {
                    pair2Y = 0;
                }
            }
            else if (pair1Y == pair2Y)
            {
                pair1X++;
                if (pair1X > 4)
                {
                    pair1X = 0;
                }
                pair2X++;
                if (pair2X > 4)
                {
                    pair2X = 0;
                }
            }
            else if (pair1X != pair2X)
            {
                int temp = pair1X;
                pair1X = pair2X;
                pair2X = temp;
            }
             final += final.toString([pair1X] [pair1Y]) + final.toString([pair2X][pair2Y]);
        }
        final = final.replace(' ', '');
        return final;
    }
```

It also gets an error here

```
final += final.toString([pair1X] [pair1Y]) + final.toString([pair2X][pair2Y]); // it says the same thing.
// and also here:
final = final.replace(' ', '');
        return final; // it says that it is an empty literal and is an illegal start of expression.
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I used Java for this, although it uses a few C# codes which I still need to change.

Comment: i think its java final is giving the error , theres no final in c#

Comment: `final` is a protected keyword in Java. Name your variable something else, and use an IDE next time.

Comment: And as a general note: compiler errors aren't always helpful, so take them with a grain of salt; if the message doesn't seem right, think of it as a clue rather than an exact reason. This is particularly true of syntax errors (as opposed to type errors, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`final` is a reserved keyword in Java and cannot be used for variable names. Rename the `final` variable.

Comment: Thank you! This helped big time.

Answer (score 2):

`final` is a keyword in java you cant use it as a variable

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is Java or C# since both are tagged. However, if it is Java, you cannot use "final" as a variable name since it is a reserved keyword. The IDE is assuming that line of code is unfinished because of that error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not compiling because of this line

```
String final = new String();
```

as a thumbrule you should never name variables with the following "java reserved words"

> abstract, continue,   for,    new,    switch,
>   assert,   default,    goto,   package,    synchronized,
>   boolean,  do, if, private,    this, break,    double, implements, protected,  throw,
>   byte, else,   import, public, throws,
>   case, enum,   instanceof, return, transient, catch,   extends,    int,    short,  try,
>   char, final,  interface,  static, void,
>   class,    finally,    long,   strictfp,   volatile, const,    float,  native, super and   while